# How do i put php variables in emails?

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email using php email() function but i am new to php, so i have brought two html files together to include php variables i have seen people input variables like $a=2; then {{2}} in the html how does this work?

Currently i am doing this which works.

```
 $to =$currentEmail;
      $subject = 'An Excercise on math4cxc.com  has  just  been  completed!';


$headers = "From: dwayne@math4cxc.com\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: dwayne@math4cxc.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \r\n"; 

$message='Hello  '
.$currentUser.'  ,'.$message;//$currentuser declared previously
$message="<html><head></head><body><i>".$message."</i></body></html>";



$file = file_get_contents('../email/index.htm', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

$file2 = file_get_contents('../email/index2.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
$message=$file.$message.$file2; //brought together as if one file
$to.=',dwayne@whatever.com';

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: So, what is not working actually?

Answer (score 0):

I guess

> i have seen people input variables like $a=2; then {{2}} in the

means parsing variable tag. I normally use PHP framework and use a function to help on that.

For you plain PHP code, it can be like

you set variable first.

```
$vars_for_display = array();
$vars_for_display['first_name'] = 'Mike';
$vars_for_display['last_name'] = 'Black';
```

Then will load string from file or your template

Your file content may look like this

```
<div>
  My name is {{first_name}}
</div>

<div>
My last name is {{last_name}}
</div>
```

And you will load string from file.

```
$file = file_get_contents('../email/index.htm', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
```

then you need to replace variable to file.

```
foreach($vars_for_display as $var_name=>$val){
   $replace_var = "{{$var_name}}";
   $file = str_replace($replace_var,$val,$file);
}
```

and them may use file content to be a message in email.